# How do I make POST form-data request with Alamofire? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, django, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to imitate this in Xcode using Alamofire:
[image: Screenshot of postman request]

Here is what I created on Swift/Xcode according to Alamofire docs :

```
let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" /* your API url */


AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "file")
    
}, to: url, method: .post)
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
    }
```

The response I get from the server is. "Number of Files: " = 0;
Meaning the server is not receiving the file, however it works when I do it from Postman, so what am I missing?

Also here is my django server which is taking the request, if this is needed:

```
 @csrf_exempt
 def test(request):

length = 0
try:
    length = len(request.FILES)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
return JsonResponse({'Number of Files: ': length})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! for anyone else who might be facing this problem, heres why:

You just have to specify the filename too.

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "file", fileName: "landing.jpeg")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                 // For Image and other params
                       if let imageNew = image {
                           let  TimeStamp = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
                        if let imageData = imageNew.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6) {
                               multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: imageParam , fileName: "\(TimeStamp + ".jpeg")",  mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                       }
                   }
                   for (key, value) in dict {
                       if value is String || value is Int {
                           multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                       }
                   }
               }, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: {
                   encodingResult in
                   switch encodingResult {
                   case .success(let upload,_,_):
                       upload.response { response in
                          // print(response)
                           
                           guard let data = response.data else { return }
                           do{
                               let userModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
                               completion(userModel)
                           }catch let error {
                               failure(error.localizedDescription)
                               print(error.localizedDescription)
                           }
                           upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                               print(response)
                               })
                       }
                   case .failure(_):
                       print("error")
                       break
                       //completion (nil)
                   }
               })
       }
```

Comment: I've already seen this. Please dont just copy code straight from another outdated post and post it as answer.